# Symfony 6 & Doctrine: delete an array of elements without looping

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

```
$em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
$contact = $em->getRepository(Contact::class)->findby(array('id'=>[1,2,3]));
$em->remove($contact);
```

will give me an error

> EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object,
> array given.

All answers I could find advise me to loop through the array and delete every record separately. I refuse to do so because I only want to send one statement to the database, resulting in SQL: *delete from table where id in (1,2,3)*

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to use the query builder, instead a loop over the remove function.

```php
$em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
$qb = $em->getRepository(Contact::class)->createQueryBuilder('c');
$affected = $qb->delete()
        ->where('c.id IN (:ids)')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute(['ids' => [1,2,3]]);
```